# MySQL - Cannot change value of float field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table structure like this:

```
Table Name: tbl_inventory_stock
id, INT, Primary Key
product_id, INT
store_id, INT
inventory_stok FLOAT
```

The value of a record that I want to update is like this:

```
id: 622
product_id: 2364
store_id: 6
inventory_stok: 2382980
```

Then I change the inventory_stok to 2382979 both directly from the table in phpmyadmin or executing syntax like this:

```
UPDATE `tbl_inventory_store` SET `inventory_stok` = '2382979' WHERE `tbl_inventory_store`.`id` = 622;
```

PHPMyAdmin displays the "0 row affected" and the inventory_stok value won't change. It's still 2382980.

Does anybody know why? I've been struggling for days, please help.

Comment: Float is not a useful datatype for the values you wish to store , Alter table and amend to an integer type.

Comment: Any error/warning message you are getting after the execution of the query ?

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html and other web discussions on float

Comment: *```.. SET `inventory_stok` = '2382979' ..```* ?? Why you set float column with string literal? use numeric value: ```.. SET `inventory_stok` = 2382979 ..```.

Comment: *PHPMyAdmin displays the "0 row affected" and the inventory_stok value won't change.* Maybe because the table name is `tbl_inventory_stock` whereas you update the table `tbl_inventory_store`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLOAT is approximate datatype with low precision.

```
SELECT CAST(2382979 AS FLOAT)
```

| CAST(2382979 AS FLOAT) |
| --- |
| 2382980 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AJeVYTBj)

Use more precise datatype. Either DOUBLE or DECIMAL (preferred).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a typo in the question table name float is just not a useful datatype amend to int using alter

```
alter table <table>
modify column inventory_stok int;
```

then update

see  https://dbfiddle.uk/6a-Gl7Uv

Can't do this? then you cannot achieve what you set out to do..